# Why is the jump link displayed on my GPT unable to jump

Tags: plugins, action, openai-api

I created a GPT and defined some actions for it. One of the actions will return a jump link, and the GPT can display the tag normally, but the href of the tag is empty.This morning it was still good. In the afternoon, I tried to release one of my GPT, but after the release, all of my GPTs, whether they have been released or not, encountered this problem

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

What I expect is that this jump link can jump to the webpage I specified, and the href value of this a tag should be my jump link